# Step through code called with exec in pdb

Tags: python, exec, pdb

I am creating a DSL by doing some pre-processing on a string, and then using exec to call the pre-processed code using the python interpreter.  I would like to be able to step through the pre-processed code using pdb, and be able to show the actual line of python code (after pre-processing) that I'm stepping through.

For example:

```
In [1]: s = '''print "hello"
   ...: print 'world'
   ...: '''

In [2]: s
Out[2]: 'print "hello"\nprint \'world\'\n'

In [3]: import pdb

In [4]: pdb.run(s)
> <string>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) list
[EOF]
```

I would like the `list` command in pdb to output the code and show what line I'm one, the same way that it does when I stop at a breakpoint in a regular python file.  Any hints on how to do this, or an alternative approach/mindset would be greatly appreciated!

[edit]

I pass in a bunch of complicated objects to the exec using the optional globals positional argument to exec, so writing out the string to a file and then running that in pdb won't work.  For example:

```
s = '''some_complicated_stateful_object.method(foo)'''

exec(s, {'some_complicated_stateful_object': an_object,
         'foo': some_other_object})
```

Thanks to for the good suggestion though!

Comment: what  about writing the `s` to a temp file, then running that?

Comment: The code references a bunch of locals passed in to the exec function. Your approach would work for the example I gave, but would not work for me.  I'll give another example.

Comment: I was encountering errors at the `<string>(1)<module>()` level. My dynamic code involved calls into other, existing code. I thought the `exec()` was masking the execution of the existing code. In reality, the error was in the string itself.

So, as long as there are no errors in the exec'ed string, you can step into the `<string>(1)<module>()` lines and get to your existing code.